# Using ASP.NET login controls wih deny="?"

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

I have a website built with ASP.NET (3.5) and want add some level of security into it.

I am using the login controls to help with this. I have one issue though.

I have within my web.config the following.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>       
</authorization>
```

This work fine when a user has not logged in before (ie. if they goto the default.aspx form then it redirects the user to the login.aspx form). But if it is a new user then I want to allow that user to enter new details using the CreateUserWizard on signup.aspx form. But for some reason it just jumps back to the login form.

Am I missing something? I thought these login controls would allow for this kind of senario?

Comment: Why is this on Community wiki? This is programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an exception allowing them access to the login page

```
<location path="SignUp.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Something like that in the System.Web node.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't notice I forgot the closing tag :P

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Authentication with Authorization.

**Authentication** is the process of obtaining identification credentials such as name and password from a user and validating those credentials against some authority.

**Authorization** determines whether an identity should be granted access to a specific resource.

The "authorization" tags you were using is a method of URL authorization. Basically you explicitly allow or deny access to a particular directory.

So, for the page where you have the signup forms you need to explicitly allow access to all users.